# Netsuite JDBC query error

Tags: jdbc, connection, netsuite, dbeaver

I am running a query with Netsuite's JDBC connection using DBeaver and I am getting the following error:

```
DBCException: SQL Error [400] [S1000]: [NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# il83cpdt109jvbi4m45oo[400]
  java.sql.SQLException: SQLException: [NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# il83cpdt109jvbi4m45oo[400]


DBCException: SQL Error [400] [S1000]: [NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# il83cpdt109jvbi4m45oo[400]
  java.sql.SQLException: SQLException: [NetSuite][SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC Driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Failed to retrieve data. Error ticket# il83cpdt109jvbi4m45oo[400]
```

Any idea of what it may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not, however you do have enough information to contact NetSuite support for assistance.

NetSuite has modified the standard database error messages to provide their own error, in your case `Error ticket# il83cpdt109jvbi4m45oo` If you contact support and reference that error code they'll be able to pinpoint the exact issue and help you out.

Now, with that said, a few things you may want to check:

- have you setup SuiteAnalytics correctly using the JDBC driver?
- What does your connection string look like? Mine is: 
  `jdbc:ns://odbcserver.netsuite.com:1708;ServerDataSource=NetSuite.com;Encrypted=1;CipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA;CustomProperties=(AccountID=123123;RoleID=3);`
- Are you authenticating with the correct role, *and* do you have permissions to perform the query you're attempting?

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you for your answer. My JDBC driver setup was correct. I was able to retrieve data from other queries. I also found my error. I was using the ISNULL Microsoft function that is not supported by the driver.  I changed it to the NVL function and now the query works fine. However, I find Netsuite's error handling awful as it didn't give me even a hint of what was wrong. Also, the "Support" portlet is disabled because I don't have enough permissions even though I am an admin (this sucks). I hope this question helps others who get similar errors find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DiegoSerrano If you're admin make sure you have the following roles added to your employee profile: `NetSuite Support Center` and `NetSuite Support Center (Basic)`. RE `ISNULL` -> Remember NetSuite is built off of `Oracle`, it seems obvious sometimes, but really easy to forget if you work with multiple DBMS :-)

Comment: Hi guys, how can I download SuiteAnalytics Connect JDBC driver? I'd like to connect to netsuite via jdbc like you. Thanks

Comment: @Emrah this is really a different questions and should be opened as such, however if you haven't contacted your account manager for the feature AND do not have the feature activated in your account, that is step 1 :)